# Load low byte of address only in x86 assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, cpu-registers, truncate

I have some assembly code:

```
mov eax, varbl
```

Where `varbl` is a pointer to .bss and evaluates to 0x6. I want to load it into just the `al` register:

```
mov al, varbl
```

but this causes a truncate error because `varbl` is 32 bits (dword) and al is byte. I can load the value of varbl in using:

```
mov al, 0x6
```

but I want to use the variable, not hardcode so that it updates when I add data to the data section.

The truncate warning is wrong. The value CAN fit in the 8-bit register and it works when I force link the program. How do I turn off this error or use some other syntax to accomplish this?

Comment: In NASM I usually do label arithmetic, such as putting `label1` at the start of a section then `label2` later in the section. The difference `label2 - label1` can be computed by the assembler without involving the linker backend.

Comment: Often something like `mov al, byte varbl` but the syntax may vary between assemblers.  It may also depend on the linker whether the appropriate relocation is supported.  What assembler are you using?

Comment: Or of course, at the cost of a couple extra bytes of code space, you can just do `mov eax, varbl` and then the low byte is in `al` anyway.

Comment: @Nate Eldrege I'm using NASM. When I do something like that it becomes a dword pointer and throws the same error...

Comment: Are you trying to assemble and link into a 64-bit PIE executable?  A 32-bit dword can hold every possible address in 32-bit mode so that error wouldn't happen.  Include a [mcve] of exact build commands you're using.

Comment: @Peter Cordes yes, but the address is an offset. I want it to give me a warning when that variable is greater than 255, but when its 8 like in my example I just want it to load the value 8 into the low byte without errors. I will still use register as address. All other bytes are already zeroed in the register. Its not doing any truncating. Why is it saying truncating? Is there a was to turn off the error?

Comment: Addresses in a 64-bit PIE executable are *not* "just an offset", they're still absolute addresses.  Maybe you're looking at unlinked `.o` files?  You're still missing a [mcve].  (Unless you mean offset as in seg:off, then the offset part is 64-bit, and seg base fixed at 0).  That's why you can only use 64-bit absolute addresses like `mov rax, label`, which needs a runtime fixup when the executable is loaded at a base address like `0x555555500000`.  If you want just an offset relative to something else (not the start of virtual address space), do `mov al, L2 - L1`.